# Enabling SSL for composer install

Tags: php, laravel, apache, composer-php, laragon

I know this question is all over the place on this site, but all the solutions haven't worked with me.

I get this error when running *composer install*:

```
In Factory.php line 650:

  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection 
  but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl
  extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, 
  by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
```

I don't know where it's getting Factory.php from but it's not in my project directory.

I did all the proposed solutions. I renamed my PHP's php.ini-development file to php.ini, and uncommented the following:

```
extension=openssl
```

And since I'm on windows, this too:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

I have also enabled SSL through Laragon menu > Apache > SSL > Enable

My php.ini file is located in my laragon folder like this:

```
C:\laragon\bin\php\PHP7\php.ini
```

**Then I noticed something: when I right-click on Laragon for the menu and go to php.ini, it says no php.ini file located (even though it's in the right spot.) As seen in [the attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hkfY.png).**

When all that didn't work, I saw another proposed solution that said to add the php.ini file to Apache's directory within Laragon as well, like this:

```
C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16\bin\php.ini
```

Note that I'm reloading Apache every time.

And I still get the error.

What could possibly be the problem? I don't want to *disable-tls* and I have no idea what the Factory.php file is.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're missing in this case is a certificate for your PHP instance.

You can download this certificate file directly from: [CURL's site](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem)

After that what you need to do is look for these entries in your **php.ini** file. Specifically `[curl]` and `[openssl]` which is right after `[curl]`.

What you need to do is save the cacert.pem file in a location preferably in a directory in your web server's root directory or where you prefer and use the absolute directory for the configuration below.

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "absolute location of where you saved the cacert.pem file"

[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
openssl.cafile= "absolute location of where you saved the cacert.pem file"
```

Save the php.ini file, restart your server and try again. This should solve your issue.

**UPDATE**

If you check your PHP info `phpinfo()` you should have a section similar to this one:
[image: phpinfo() openssl]

If you don't you're probably not enabling openssl.

Comment: So this definitely fixed one thing: the popup that says "no php.ini file located" no longer comes up so thank you for that. However, the initial error within the terminal about openssl being required still comes up.

Comment: If you check `phpinfo()` do you get the openssl section?

Comment: I added an example of how your `phpinfo()` should look if you have openssl enabled.

Comment: I've figured out my problem, thank you :) If you're curious, I added it in the update in the question.

Comment: As an extra info, composer usually uses a specific version of php which is configured on install using the environment variable used for php.exe. So you were probably running composer with the other php version.

Comment: Yes but I didn’t put another php version other than 7.4 in composer the first time. It was a new laptop and php 7.4 was my first and only install of php and the same one I used for composer install the first time. Then I had installed Laragon which came with php8 and it used 8 as default, I switched laragon’s to 7, then composer got confused until I uninstalled composer and reinstalled again. 
Btw I would give you an upvote but I require 15 reputation haha

Comment: No worries! As for the composer thing, yeah, when you do new php version installs you should check which version it's using. At least on Windows the easiest option I think is to reinstall composer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. To anyone else who needs it:

It's everything I did above, then as an initial step, what the other answer said which solves the "no file found" popup. But to solve the rest, I've figured out my problem was that before I did everything above in php.ini, I switched the php version Laragon was using (v8) to v7.4 (the one I've been trying to get to work.) This, for some reason, confuses Composer. So I had to uninstall composer itself from my computer and reinstall, but activate `developer option` by checking it in the installation wizard this time since I hadn't the first time around. After that, it worked.